# Separate simple and double click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I need on a DataGridView to have events for both simple & double clicks. The problem is : the simple click is called on the first click, opens the new window, therefore double click can never be achieved.
Any way to tell the program to wait till you know whether it is a double click, apart from a waiting time in code, which is both fastidious and does not take into account the user set time for double click?

```
Private Sub Data_DClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Data.DoubleClick
    msgbox("never called")
End Sub
Private Sub Data_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Data.Click
    MsgBox("this gets in the way")
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView Double-click Event in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018763/gridview-double-click-event-in-asp-net)

Comment: @RyanWilson : this is in-code handling, what I wanted to avoid. But if this site does use it, maybe it's impossible otherwise...

Comment: There is a number of Dispaly Technologies and just about every one of them has their own DataGrid and related classes. So you need to be a bit more specific what display technlogy you are using (Console, WinForms, WPF/UWP, ASP.Net, Other)

Comment: @Christopher : winForms

Comment: There is apparently a official Document on this specific case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-distinguish-between-clicks-and-double-clicks It sees to say "either roll back the single click" or "delay execution of hte single click until you are certain it is not a double click".